# Angular2 Observable, interating through object in service gives errors

Tags: arrays, angular, angular2-services, angular2-observables

I've looked on the board and on many sites but can't find a solution to my issue.

The issue has already been discussed but nothing seems to work on my code.
So! First, the JSON produced by my middleware is like so:

```
{
  "uuid": "5c5260ec-5bcd-451a-ad68-57eb9572c185",
  "latitude": 41,
  "longitude": 1,
  "temoin": {
    "numeroDeTelephone": 342391,
    "nom": "bruce",
    "prenom": "wayne",
    "sexe": "m",
    "age": 12,
    "taille": 150,
    "poids": 62,
    "groupeSanguin": "a+"
  }
}
```

As you can see, I have two objects (which are described in my Angular app) the main object is `signalement` which contains a `temoin` object.

**Signalement**:

```
import { TemoinObjet } from './temoin.objet';

export class Signalement{
    public uuid: String;
    public latitude: any;
    public longitude: any;
    public temoin: TemoinObjet;    
}
```

**Temoin**:

```
export class TemoinObjet{
    public telephone: Number;
    public prenom: String;
    public nom: String;
    public sexe: String;
    public age: Number;
    public taille: Number;
    public poids: Number;
    public groupeSanguin: String;
}
```

I switched from promises in the component to a service intended to get data:

```
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { Signalement } from '../domain/objets/signalement.objet';
import { TemoinObjet } from '../domain/objets/temoin.objet';

@Injectable()
export class SignalementService{  
    private urlRef: string = 'http://localhost:8080/Asklepios-1.0/ws/signalement';

    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    recupererSignalements():Observable<Signalement[]>{
        return this.http.get(this.urlRef).map((res:Response) => res.json());
    }

    get(uuidARetrouver: String, liste:any) : Signalement{
         return liste.find(s => s.uuid === uuidARetrouver);
    }
}
```

I'm using the `recupererSignalements()` method which returns an Observable.

In my component I've created a method with the same name and called it in the `ngOnInit`. Here's the full component:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Signalement } from './domain/objets/signalement.objet';
import { SignalementService } from './services/signalement.service';
import { TemoinObjet } from './domain/objets/temoin.objet';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
    selector: 'liste-signalement',
    templateUrl: './list_signalement.html',
    providers: [SignalementService]

})

export class ListSignalementsComponent implements OnInit {
    signalements: Signalement[];

    constructor(private signalementService: SignalementService){
    }

        ngOnInit(){
            this.recupererSignalements();
            console.log(this.signalements);
           }

           recupererSignalements(){
               this.signalementService.recupererSignalements().subscribe(donnees => this.signalements = donnees, ()=>console.log("Fail"), ()=>console.log("Done : "+this.signalements));
           }
}
```

Once it's done I want to iterate over the `signalements` array to show the information in my view, but everytime I get the error `Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]' at DefaultIterableDiffer.diff`. When using `*ngFor` I instead see:

```
Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type
'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. at 
NgForOf.ngOnChanges.
```

Here's the view :

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let signalement of signalements">
        {{signalement.uuid}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've tried the `asyncpipe`. Using this I get no more errors but can't see anything in my view.

Comment: Try changing this:  return this.http.get(this.urlRef).map((res:Response) => res.json()); to this:
 `return this.http.get(this.urlRef)
                .map((res:Response) => res.json())
                .do(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)));`
And see what that returns...(Well, I guess I cannot format code in the comments section ... hope you can read this ok.)

Comment: Also, are you expecting to get back one of these? Or an array of these? This code is implying an array: `Observable<Signalement[]>`

Comment: I'm expecting an array indeed.

For the stringify I got another error : TypeError: this.http.get(...).map(...).do is not a function

Also when i do a console.log in the subscribe i get this :

Object {uuid: "5c5260ec-5bcd-451a-ad68-57eb9572c185", latitude: 41, longitude: 1, temoin: Object}
latitude
:
41
longitude
:
1
temoin
:
Object
uuid
:
"5c5260ec-5bcd-451a-ad68-57eb9572c185"
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: do requires another import.

Comment: import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

Comment: Any way you could turn this into a run-able plunker?

Comment: Ok just find out after 4 days ... I am trying to process it as an array and it is everything but an array. I'm sorry, problem solved T_T thanks Deborah

Comment: Glad you were able to resolve it!

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that ngFor expects an array – although it's the equivalent of ng-repeat in Angular 2+ world, it was designed to only operate on arrays which removes the need to account for the many edge cases ng-repeat covered, including iterating over non-iterables (such as objects, in your case).

If you're just looking to render a list of Signalements, then the one Signalement just needs to be inside an array. If you're trying to iterate over the properties of one Signalement, you would need to write a pipe that converts an object into an array of keys, such as the "keys" pipe in the 'ngx-pipes' library.